# Deploy using Capistrano and Ruby 2.5.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, capistrano, bundler

I upgraded Ruby to version 2.5.1, RubyGems to 2.7.6 and Bundler to 1.16.1, all the most recent versions. Locally everything is fine, but when I try to run the *sidekiq:quiet* task while deploying using Capistrano, I get the following error message:

> ** bundler: failed to load command: sidekiqctl (/var/www/test/htdocs/shared/bundle/ruby-2.5.1@gapfish/ruby/2.5.0/bin/sidekiqctl)
>   *** LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/dep_proxy

I already tried to run `gem update --system` and `gem install bundler` but didn't help. Anyone has some clue about what could be happening?

If I require dep_proxy inside the machine (using irb), it can be found however.

> gapfish@stage ~/current $ irb
>   2.5.1 :001 > require 'bundler/dep_proxy'  => true

- gem env:

  RubyGems Environment:

  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.7.6

    - RUBY VERSION: 2.5.1 (2018-03-29 patchlevel 57) [x86_64-linux]
    - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
    - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.gem/ruby/2.5.0
    - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby
    - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
    - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.gem/specs
    - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/etc
    - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
    - GEM PATHS:

      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1
      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global
    - GEM CONFIGURATION:

      - :update_sources => true
      - :verbose => true
      - :backtrace => false
      - :bulk_threshold => 1000
      - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
    - REMOTE SOURCES:

      - https://rubygems.org/
    - SHELL PATH:

      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/bin
      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1@global/bin
      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin
      - /var/www/www.gapfish.com/htdocs/.rvm/bin
      - /usr/local/bin
      - /usr/bin
      - /bin
      - /opt/bin
      - /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.9.3

Comment: Does your app use the `bootsnap` gem? If so, try removing it.

Comment: No, it doesn't use this gem

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading bundler to 1.15.4 worked for me.. :(
I was trying with 1.16.1, didn't test with 1.16.0 though

Until today there was no bugfix in Bundler